# Test with Student's t

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, t-test, t-distribution

What kind of null hypothesis can be tested using a Student's t?

It's very likely to be one of the questions of the statistics exam. In order to test a null hypothesis using the Student's t, does it need to have particular features?

Answer (score 6):

> What kind of null hypothesis can be tested using a Student's t?

Generally speaking we're testing means in some way -

For example, a one-sample test of a population mean being equal to a specified value, or a two sample test of equality of population means (both under normal assumptions). However, t-tests arise in other contexts, such as ANOVA and regression.

> In order to test a null hypothesis using the Student's t, does it need to have particular features?

Two situations could have an *identical* null hypothesis but require different tests. The null hypothesis itself is not the only determinant of which test is suitable.

For example, consider a test of equality of means for two gamma-distributed variables, or two Bernoulli-distributed variables. In both cases, you can phrase the null as a equality of population means, but you normally wouldn't do a t-test for either.